# Can Swift be used for web?

Tags: web, backend, swift

Can [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) be used for the web (as a backend technology)? Is that good idea?

**edited:**

There are many languages to write. All of them have their pros and cons. I know many languages are not profitable to use for everything. For example, Python is faster then Java, etc. And I asked question like that, to be compared and get theoretical knowledge...

Comment: Just as easily as Objective-C would have been - you can rely on the same frameworks and third-party libraries. This might be a little broad for SO though.

Comment: Just I don't know if someone used Objective-C for that.. Is that good practice?

Comment: The Gwan webservcie supports pages written in Objective C. 
See: http://gwan.ch/developers#tab13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift should be able to use all available [Objective-C web frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519324/web-application-programming-using-objective-c), and there's an interesting historical connection to [WebObjects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebObjects), but there are a lot more resources out there for developing web applications with Java, C#, Ruby, JavaScript, and Python.